# Generalizing round segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, line

I have a polyline feature class and I need some segments to be generalized. I tried exactly Generalize tool in Advanced Editor toolbar as well as Simplify Line tool, but it isn't what I need.

[image]

My goal is to make round segments of rectangular shape, see an example. I need to transform the initial thin line into almost the same but instead of round segments (they're not curves) want to have angles like thick red ones in a picture.  Tried to build a script using lengths of distances between vectors from beginning of line with help of `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` and `arcpy.positionAlongLine()`, but nothing useful came to my mind.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you want Smooth Line: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/smooth-line.htm

Comment: Do you want the right-angle (red line) or the curve? I can't quite tell from your description.

Comment: Is line split already at the start and end of red segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution below assumes that you split your line. It is much bigger beast if you'd like to find split points first.

Select segment to modify and run this:

```
"""
knee maker
"""
import arcpy
import numpy as np
infc="SEGMENTS"
g = arcpy.Geometry()
segment = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(infc, g)[0]
##  FIND TANGENT AT START
pStart = segment.firstPoint
X1,Y1 = pStart.X,pStart.Y
pMid = segment.positionAlongLine (0.01).firstPoint
XM,YM = pMid.X,pMid.Y
aStart,bStart=np.polyfit([X1,XM],[Y1,YM],1)
##  FIND TANGENT AT THE END
pEnd = segment.lastPoint
X1,Y1 = pEnd.X,pEnd.Y
pMid = segment.positionAlongLine (segment.length-0.01).firstPoint
XM,YM = pMid.X,pMid.Y
aEnd,bEnd=np.polyfit([X1,XM],[Y1,YM],1)
##  FIND INTERSECTION. QUIT IF TANGENTS ARE PARALLEL
if aStart==aEnd:exit()
x,y = np.polyfit([aStart,aEnd],[-bStart,-bEnd],1)
pMid=arcpy.Point(x,-y)
pLine=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([pStart,pMid,pEnd]))
##  REDRAW LINE
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,"Shape@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=pLine
        cursor.updateRow(row)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

[image]

I used filet tool to draw curve connecting 2 straight lines. As expected mid point of modified segment sits slightly below "theoretical" intersection point.
So split original somewhere on a straight parts.

Comment: exactly what I thought about! However, the next step is to detect these kinds of round-shaped chunks n a polyline.

Comment: Post a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I would think either Generalize or Densify might do the trick.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/generalize.htm

If you're having issues with Generalize, I'd personally set a low offset value to minimize the change to your line.

Densify might give you a little more control, because you can specify a maximum offset, maximum angle, or maximum distance

Also, don't be afraid to run it through the tool more than once to see if you get a better result from a couple of passes.